# html table with column size matching

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a table with 6 columns. The first column has a line of text and will be the widest column. The remaining 5 columns will have headers with text that will be loaded dynamically, so I don't know the widths in advance.

This table is styled with Bootstrap (v3.3) and needs to be responsive.

Is there a way to size the first column to a set size and then size the remaining columns so they are all be the same width, based on the largest text value?

Here is the table with only the header and first row shown. As you can see the header columns have different widths.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Terrible</th>
      <th>Bad</th>
      <th>Average</th>
      <th>Good</th>
      <th>Excellent</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>How was the food in the hotel</td>
    <td class="text-center">o</td>
    <td class="text-center">o</td>
    <td class="text-center">o</td>
    <td class="text-center">o</td>
    <td class="text-center">o</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is a [demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kgjertsen/cetfghz4/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this is helps!

Basically, you can just JavaScript to find the widest column, (ignoring the empty ones) to give you the max-width. Then set the columns to that width.

See the fiddle below :)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  var largestWidth;

  jQuery('.table').each(function(index, element){
    largestWidth = 0; // Reset the width for every table (presuming we want this to affect every table)

    jQuery(element).find('th').each(function(innerIndex, innerElement){
      console.log(largestWidth);
      if(jQuery(innerElement).width() > largestWidth && jQuery(innerElement).html() !== ''){
        largestWidth = jQuery(innerElement).width(); //Set to new highest width.
      }
    });

    jQuery(element).find('th:not(:first-child)').width(largestWidth + 'px'); // Set all but first column to highest width.
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cetfghz4/4/

Comment: While this definitely works, i'm wondering if there's a CSS oriented solution with less code?

Comment: There might be, if I was going to, I'd use `table-layout: fixed` but there'd be problems with the left hand column. It'd be interesting if anyone knows a CSS solution.

Comment: I was hoping for a CSS solution. This works, but the first column is included in the resizing, but it should take up the remaining space.

Comment: I had hoped for a Bootstrap CSS solution, but this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like that :

```
<tr>
   <th class="col-xs-2 col-sm-7"></th>
   <th class="col-xs-2 col-sm-1">Terrible</th>
   <th class="col-xs-2 col-sm-1">Bad</th>
   <th class="col-xs-2 col-sm-1">Average</th>
   <th class="col-xs-2 col-sm-1">Good</th>
   <th class="col-xs-2 col-sm-1">Excellent</th>
</tr>
```

[demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qw3epw1b/2/)

You will have to give even more effort to make columns header responsive (like right media queries to put the header text vertically) but this solution will work for the column width issue.

has it's a bootstrap native class, you could find more documentation [here](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/)

I hope it may help

Comment: This doesn't resize the last 5 columns!

Comment: I have edited my post to add some improvements (see : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/Media_queries) content will be resized on small screens. I think it's the better way to do those things

Answer (score 0):

Make it a fancy party, use `flexbox`:

```
<div class="flex-row">
    <div class="question">Some question</div>
    <div class="option">Option</div>
    <div class="option">Option</div>
    <div class="option">Option</div>
    <div class="option">Option</div>
    <div class="option">Option</div>
</div>

.flex-row {
    display: flex;
}

.question {
    flex: 5;
}

.option {
    flex: 1;
}
```